# Drawing liaisons (arcs) below text to mark elision

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, arc

In French, words are not pronounced independently: when two words are adjacent, [elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision) may happen, for instance.

How can I draw these bindings below the words in form of little arcs? I'm working with LaTeX and can use the LuaTeX engine if necessary.

[image: liaisons]

Note:

- in the first line of this picture, the leftmost arc starts below the “s”;
- in the second line, the leftmost arc starts below the second “l”.

Comment: The undertie glyph U+203F in unicode can do that: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\begin{document}
nous ^^^^203f avon

elle ^^^^203f a ^^^^203f faim
\end{document}`, but you will need xelatex/lualatex for that.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this doesn't work for me. Don't know why. I'm getting "nous [] avon elle [] a [] faim". Besides this in my second example I need the arc from l to a.

Comment: ‿ is a character or glyph. To print a glyph, you need to use a font that has that glyph: ‿‾‽※⁂‸. The undertie is used to represent *liaison* in French, where a word-final consonant (no longer normally pronounced, like the `s` in `les` [the]) *is* pronounced because the following word begins with a vowel: les pommes [the apples] = /le pom/; les amis [the friends] = /lez‿ami/. Tikz is a good solution, especially if you don't have a font, or can't use xelatex/lualatex. `newunicodechar` is another option, it can be used in pdflatex (still need a font, though, or some other way to print the shape).

Comment: Thank you. I took your code from the first comment and compiled it with lualatex and got what I wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you really wanted—according to [your comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531084/how-to-draw-liaisons-arcs-below-text/531103?noredirect=1#comment1342922_531103)—wasn't clear **at all** in the question. So, I'm left with four different examples to attempt to implement your wishes.

## Extreme simplification of the flexible code given last

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\liaison}{%
  \tikz[baseline=0pt] \draw (0,0) to[bend right=20] (0.2,0);%
}

\begin{document}

Nous\liaison avons mangé des\liaison amandes grillées.

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Drawing the liaisons between arbitrary places in the document

This can be done with the `tikzmark` Ti*k*Z library:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \liaison { O{0.5mm} O{20} m m }
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember~picture, overlay]
      \draw ([yshift=-#1]#3.south) to[bend~right=#2] ([yshift=-#1]#4.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

El\tikzmarknode{A}{l}e \tikzmarknode{B}{a} faim.\liaison{A}{B}

Please fr\tikzmarknode{here}{o}bnicate the damn toa\tikzmarknode{there}{s}ter.%
\liaison{here}{there}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Code that makes the arcs terminate below the “south points” of just-before and just-after letters

Here is code that makes the arcs start and end below the “south points” of the relevant letters:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__Nik_clist
\tl_new:N \l__Nik_last_before_tl
\tl_new:N \l__Nik_first_after_tl

\NewDocumentCommand \liaison { O{0.5mm} m }
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l__Nik_clist {#2}
    \clist_pop:NN \l__Nik_clist \l__Nik_last_before_tl
    \clist_pop:NN \l__Nik_clist \l__Nik_first_after_tl

    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base), nodes={inner~sep=0}]
      \draw node (a) {\l__Nik_last_before_tl}
            node[right=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ma~liaison/width}~of~a]
              (b) {\l__Nik_first_after_tl}
            ([yshift=-#1]a.south) to[bend~right=20]
            ([yshift=-#1]b.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \ignorespaces
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\tikzset{ma liaison/width/.initial=0.2}

% Set /tikz/ma liaison/width to the width of an interword space in the font
% current at the beginning of the document. Comment out if you prefer to use
% the above default.
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \tikzset{ma liaison/width/.expand once=\the\fontdimen2\font}%
}

\begin{document}

Nou\liaison{s,a} vons mangé de\liaison{s,a} mandes grillées.

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Flexible code (arcs end at letter corners)

Here is a Ti*k*Z-based solution with a bunch of knobs to set defaults or fine-tune the result:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% The following 3 packages are only used here to provide good typography and
% PDF output with the sample text in French.
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}          % comment this out if your TikZ is too old

\tikzset{
  ma liaison/.is family,
  ma liaison/bend amount/.initial=20,
  % The following three values are in x units of the TikZ xyz coordinate system.
  ma liaison/width/.initial=0.2,
  ma liaison/left padding/.initial=0.01,
  ma liaison/right padding/.initial=0.01,
  ma liaison/padding/.style={left padding={#1}, right padding={#1}},
  ma liaison/color/.initial=blue!40,
  ma liaison/default options/.style={line cap=round},
  ma liaison/other options/.style={/tikz/.cd, #1},
}

\newcommand*{\liaison}[1][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0pt, ma liaison/default options, ma liaison, #1]
    \draw[color/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ma liaison/color}]
      (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ma liaison/left padding}, 0)
      (0,0) to[bend right=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ma liaison/bend amount}]
      (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ma liaison/width}, 0)
      +(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ma liaison/right padding}, 0);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

Nous\liaison avons mangé des\liaison amandes grillées. Elles\liaison étaient
délicieuses !

On peut aussi faire des liaisons\liaison[color=red!40, width=1.5cm] à
rallonge... pour les amateurs.

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
Another example of customization: before%
\liaison[color=green!40!blue, width=4, bend amount=15, padding=0.2,
         other options={line width=2pt}] % space token ignored due to the
                                         % \ignorespaces
after.
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have a lot of *liaisons* with the same graphical aspect in your document, you might want to save the corresponding `tikzpicture` in a box and print it with `\usebox` in order to speed up the compilation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hoped/hope for an easier solution. I don't understand your code completely. I will work through it. But meanwhile: How can I draw the binding like in my second example from l to a? And how can I change the anchor points to south?

Comment: @Nik I have added a fourth example to allow drawing liaisons between arbitrary letters or other boxed material. This is the second one presented in the answer.

Comment: Thank you. With my second example I wanted to make clear that in "elle" the last "e" is not spoken. That's why the connection is between "l" and "a". Sorry if this was not clear. Maybe this is unusual but I find this helpful.

Comment: Okay, understood. Next time, please describe precisely in the question the desired layout and constraints. The picture helps but doesn't always make everything clear and obvious.