# How do you typeset '‿'s and 'x's inbetween words for French liaisons?

Tags: french

I want to typeset a French document with the grammar marked. Example:

Je suis‿en seconde.

I also want to have a small 'x' in between two words when a liaison is impossible and add parenthesis around the ‿ when the liaison is optional. How can I do this in LaTeX?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531084/drawing-liaisons-arcs-below-text-to-mark-elision ?

Comment: Without TikZ, a poor man's solution may be `\newcommand\myliaison{\setbox0=\hbox{$\smile$}\hbox{\lower\ht0\hbox{$\smile$}}}` and in XeTeX/LuaTeX you can input the symbol directly